# Can Chromecast stream content over WiFi

Tags: chromecast

If the chromecast dongle is plugged into an HDMI port on the TV and its power cord is plugged into a USB port on the TV, can it stream content over a WiFi router if there is no other device such as a phone or tablet? Or is chromecast simply a way of displaying to the TV screen content that is being streamed to another device?

The TV does not have the Youtube TV app (too old).

Comment: Your second hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

Chromecast streams its own media over Wifi from the internet but it needs a mobile device to initiate and control the stream (for example to stop, pause or skip).

Comment: Thanks. I found a how-to page saying that it might be possible to control chromecast with the TV's remote using HDMI-CEC (if the TV supports that feature and "Deck Control").

Comment: True, most modern TVs support this via the TV remote. You still need a mobile device to tell the Chromecast what to stream.

Answer (score 1):

Content is streamed **to** not **from** the dongle.

And you always need another device, typically a phone or tablet but also regular PCs with Chrome and an extension, to stream to and "control" the dongle.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might work like FireTV.

Comment: FireTV is a media player, Android based and with its own remote control. It's a full featured Android computer, unlike the Chromecast .